# MVC async child actions not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a new MVC5 website with a view that has a call to a child action contained within it. This child action uses the "async" keyword as it does some DB work.

This works locally no problem using IIS Express, however if I run this on a windows server 2008 R2 running IIS 7.5 I get the following obscure error:

```
Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.
```

I have read that MVC is not fully async capable, but why would this work in IIS Express if that was the issue? It took a while to realise that this was a problem with the "async" action as all other views worked no problem in both environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Child actions currently are not capable of being run asynchronously. That will change in MVC 6, but of course, so will the whole concept of child actions, too, for what it's worth.

In the meantime, anything you do in a child action must be done synchronously.

Comment: So why would this work when run locally in IIS express through visual studio?

Comment: Good question. Honestly, I'm not sure how you got it to work there, even. Child actions are totally incompatible with async. There's actually a good many outstanding bug reports and feature requests regarding this.