# asynchronous call deadlock in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5.2

We want to display version detail from our back end services on the bottom of all pages.

The 3 backend services are async webapi(2.2) calls, we need to make these 3 async calls aggregate the date into a model and then pass that to the View.

If i do this as part of a (not-child) controller action the code works and displays the data.

However trying to display this data at the bottom of every page (child action) gives several differing async deadlock type conditions.

**child action and call on _layout.cshtml**

```
    //ControllerAction
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult VersionInfo()
    {
        var version = _versionInfoViewModelMapper.Map().Result;
        return View(version);...
    }

//Layout.cshtml
    @if(Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        Html.RenderAction("VersionInfo", "Utils");
    }
```

This results in what seems to be a deadlock as the request doesn't end,

**using An ActionFilter**

```
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //viewBag.VersionInfo = Task.Run(() => _versionInfoViewModelMapper.Map()).Result;
            viewBag.VersionInfo = _versionInfoViewModelMapper.Map().Result;
        }
    }
```

using the above filter to pass the data to the ViewBag which is then used, gives the same endless call.

If I don't use the .Result on the async calls i get an Error

> HttpServerUtility.Execute blocked while waiting for an asynchronous
>   operation to complete.

Is there a way i can get around this issue? potentially by using a Global.asax Application_PostAuthenticateRequest or similar event?

Comment: It seems async is not supported in child actions, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739114/asp-net-mvc-4-async-child-action) or [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28680288/mvc-async-child-actions-not-working-in-iis). The request [in codeplex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601) was closed as "added in MVC 6 as part of the View Components"

Comment: Does wrapping with `Task.Run` not work?

Comment: yeah thats why i came to this issue after initially trying an async child action.

Comment: @Kędrzu i cannot remember which of the error states it gave but that failed as well you can see i had this commented out in the actionfilter attempt.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies here:

```
_versionInfoViewModelMapper.Map().Result;
```

Calling `Task.Result`, as well as `Task.Wait()` in case there is a `SynchronizationContext` set (which is true in ASP environment) may lead to serious deadlocks.

Instead use async version of your method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> VersionInfo()
{
    var version = await _versionInfoViewModelMapper.Map();
    return View(version);...
}
```

For more info about this problem see [this Stephen Cleary blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: you cannot have async child tasks, i started with this and got errors which resulted in me investigating other methods.  follow links off this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519253/awaited-async-method-not-returning-before-result-is-required

Comment: Yes, I just investigated this.